# Immutable объект в Java

Tags: java

В `java` все объект могут быть `mutable` и `immutable`. Понятно, что, например, строка является `immutable`. Но если я хочу создать собственный `immutable` тип, то какие требования он должен выполнять ?

У меня есть такой пример:

```
public class ImmutableObject {

    private final String string;
    private final Date date;

    public ImmutableObject(String string, Date date) {
        this.string = string;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return new Date(date.getTime());
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

}
```

Могу ли я его считать неизменяемым ? Обязательно ли поля должны быть `final` ? И если одно из полей, например строка, не будет `final`, то объект данного класса можно считать неизменным ? Учитывает ли данный класс все подводные камни многопоточности ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, поля обязательно должны быть `final`.

Я бы не поставил знак равенства между между Immutable объектом и объектом, имеющим методы только для чтения.
Дело в том, что в качестве оптимизации, компилятор может запросто переставлять строки с инструкциями, это так называемый reordering. В результате может получиться так, что ваш объект будет доступен из других потоков, но его переменные могут не быть проинициализированы. В однопоточных приложениях это в принципе не страшно, но вот если вы работаете в многопоточной среде, то final защитит ваши переменные от таких перестановок.

Теперь по существу ваших вопросов:

1. Да, объекты вашего класса можно считать неизменяемым.
2. В многопоточной среде обязательно.
3. Если строка будет не final, то такой объект уже не Immutable.

Comment: Не очень понял как перестановка инструкций может повлиять на отсутсвие сеттеров. Вы говорите о том, что final нужен только для защиты от сеттеров и изменении ссылки на объект в куче, так ? Не понял третий пункт, зачем нужен `final` без сеттеров ? И зачем нам вообще сеттеры, если у нас ссылка `final`. Да и вообще, `final` не спасет, если мы, например, сделаем `getDate()` и потом через геттер поменяет свойства даты.

Comment: @faoxis Может получиться так, что после выхода из конструктора, ваши поля останутся непроинициализированными

Comment: Да, и почему строка обязана быть тоже `final` ? Ведь если у нас один из параметров уже `final`, то компилятор не даст ссылку на не полностью сконструированный объект, так ? Ведь, как минимум, один final будет инициализирован в конструкторе.

Comment: @faoxis, а как вы измените поле date через геттер? У вас в геттере создается новый объект new Date(). Вы можете поменять только его

Comment: @faoxis, нет, не так. Может получиться так, что конструируемый объект будет доступен с других потоков с непроинициализированной строкой

Comment: Добавлю свою пять копеек, есть такое понятие как effective immutable object, это объекты которые имеют только геттеры, и не имеющие методов для изменения состояния. Это позволяет сделать ленивую инициализацию некоторых полей избегая оверхеда по памяти. И еще, в многопоточной среде, final совсем не обязателен :) Например, объявление полей как volatile позволит избежать того самого реординга.